# string vs String - single case discriminated union

Tags: .net, string, f#

[If `string` is an alias of String in the .net framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd323829.aspx) why does this happen and how should I interpret it:

```
type JustAString = string
> type JustAString = string

type JustAStringAgain = String 
> type JustAStringAgain = | String
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The existing answer is correct in that `string` is an F# type while `String` is not a type (unless you open the `System` namespace), which is why the two definitions differ. The first case creates a type alias, while the second one declares a *discriminated union* (rather than a module alias as suggested in the existing answer).

In the first case, the definition creates just a type alias. We can check this using `typeof<T>`:

```
> type MyString = string;;

> typeof<MyString>.FullName;;
val it : string = "System.String"
```

In the second case, you are defining a discriminated union that has a single case named `String` (the name could have been anything - the key thing is that `String` is not a known type and so it is treated just as a name of the case). To check this, we can use `GetUnionCases` from the F# reflection module:

```
> type MyString = String;;
type MyString = | String

> open Microsoft.FSharp.Reflection
  for u in FSharpType.GetUnionCases(typeof<MyString>) do 
    printfn "%s" u.Name;;
String
val it : unit = ()
```

The definition is simply a very basic case of discriminated union. We could add more cases and the cases could contain fields too:

```
type MyString = String | SomeOtherName of int
```

The trick is that `String` is not a known type name. If you open the `System` namespace, then you get just a type alias again:

```
> open System;;
> type MyString = String;;

> typeof<MyString>.FullName;;
val it : string = "System.String"
```